# whats app calling update

Tags: whatsapp

Do windows 8.1 have calling feature in what's app because I update my what's app 2time since the calling feature comes in to the market but it doesn't come into my Lumia 525

Comment: Still the what's app calling feature for windows in the present version is not yet available.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp version 2.12.72 has calling feature, u can now get the update.

Answer (score 0):

Current Version 2.11.690.0 of whats app doesnt have whats app calling feature. But recent update just fixed some minor stability bugs